# OpenGL how to move the camera upward and then come back on the Grid

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I want to implement a conventional FPS control. By pressing the spacebar the camera moves upward and then comes down back on the grid, simulating the jumping action. Right now, I am only able to move the camera upward for a distance but I don't know how to let the camera come down.

This is my camera class:

```
Camera::Camera(glm::vec3 cameraPosition, glm::vec3 cameraFront, glm::vec3 cameraUp){
   position = glm::vec3(cameraPosition);
   front = glm::vec3(cameraFront);
   up = glm::vec3(cameraUp);

   // Set to predefined defaults
   yawAngle = -90.0f;
   pitchAngle = 0.0f;
   fieldOfViewAngle = 45.0f;
}

Camera::~Camera() {}

void Camera::panCamera(float yaw){
yawAngle += yaw;

updateCamera();}    

void Camera::tiltCamera(float pitch){
    pitchAngle += pitch;
    // Ensure pitch is inbounds for both + and - values to prevent irregular behavior
    pitchAngle >  89.0f ? pitchAngle =  89.0f : NULL;
    pitchAngle < -89.0f ? pitchAngle = -89.0f : NULL;

    updateCamera();}

void Camera::zoomCamera(float zoom){
    if (fieldOfViewAngle >= MIN_ZOOM && fieldOfViewAngle <= MAX_ZOOM){
        fieldOfViewAngle -= zoom * 0.1;}

    // Limit zoom values to prevent irregular behavior
    fieldOfViewAngle <= MIN_ZOOM ? fieldOfViewAngle = MIN_ZOOM : NULL;
    fieldOfViewAngle >= MAX_ZOOM ? fieldOfViewAngle = MAX_ZOOM : NULL;}

glm::mat4 Camera::calculateViewMatrix(){
    return glm::lookAt(position, position + front, up);}

void Camera::updateCamera(){
    front.x = cos(glm::radians(yawAngle)) * cos(glm::radians(pitchAngle));
    front.y = sin(glm::radians(pitchAngle));
    front.z = sin(glm::radians(yawAngle)) * cos(glm::radians(pitchAngle));
    front = glm::normalize(front);}

void Camera::moveForward(float speed){
    position += speed * front;}

void Camera::moveBackward(float speed){
    position -= speed * front;}

void Camera::moveLeft(float speed){
    position -= glm::normalize(glm::cross(front, up)) * speed;}

void Camera::moveRight(float speed){
    position += glm::normalize(glm::cross(front, up)) * speed;}

void Camera::moveUpward(float speed){
    position.y += speed;}
```

This is how I implement it in main.cpp:

```
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS)
{
    camera.moveUpward(cameraSpeed);
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you need to move the camera downward when the user is not pressing space, but only if it's above the grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a jump by applying an acceleration to the y-position. You'll need to add 3 new attributes to your struct: acceleration (vec3), velocity (vec3), and onGround (boolean).

```
void Camera::jump() {
    // Apply a upwards acceleration of 10 units. You can experiment with 
    // this value or make it physically correct and calculate the 
    // best value, but this requires the rest of your program to
    // be in well-defined units.
    this->onGround = false;
    this->acceleration.y = 10.0f;
}


void Camera::update() {
    // Your other update code

    // The acceleration should decrease with gravity. 
    // Eventually it'll become negative.
    this->acceleration.y += GRAVITY;  // Define 'GRAVITY' to a negative constant.

    // Only update if we're not on the ground.
    if (!this->onGround) {
        // Add the acceleration to the velocity and the velocity to 
        // the position. 
        this->velocity.y += this->acceleration.y
        this->position.y += this->velocity.y;
        if (this->position.y <= 0) {
            // When you're on the ground, reset the variables.
            this->onGround = true;
            this->acceleration.y = 0;
            this->velocity.y = 0;
            this->position.y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And in your event handling you'll call the jump method.

```
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS)
{
    camera.jump();
}
```

However, this code probably shouldn't be on the camera, but instead on a Physics object of some sort. But it'll work.